# subfig reference layout

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

I have the following working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Error} This should say Fig. 1\textbf{a}, not \ref{sf1}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfig 1]{\label{sf1} Contents of the sub-figure}
\qquad
\subfloat[Subfig 2]{\label{sf2} Contents of the sub-figure}
\caption{\textbf{Error} This should only say \textbf{b}, not \ref{sf2}}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Basically my problem it stated in the MWE above.

1. When I reference a subfigure inside the figure caption, I want it only to refer to the **bolded** letter
2. When I reference a subfigure outside the figure caption, I want it to refer to the figure number + the **bolded** letter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use the command `\subref` instead of `\ref`. Please note that the command `subref` is fragile so you have either protect it inside `caption` or make the command robust.
2. Use `\subref*`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\DeclareSubrefFormat{subbold}{#1\textbf{#2}}%for \subref*
\DeclareCaptionListOfFormat{subbold}{\textbf{#2}}%for subref
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={bf},listofformat=subbold,subrefformat=subbold}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\subref
\begin{document}

\textbf{Error} This should say Fig. 1\textbf{a}, not \subref*{sf1}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Subfig 1]{\label{sf1} Contents of the sub-figure}
\qquad
\subfloat[Subfig 2]{\label{sf2} Contents of the sub-figure}
\caption{\textbf{Error} This should only say \textbf{b}, not \subref{sf2}}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: 1: Thanks, you are right. However, that produces (b), not a bolded b as I desire. 2: The letter is not bolded by `\ref`.

Comment: @BillyJean: Fixed it.